# How to troubleshoot GraphQL file upload issue with Nest.js application on Google Cloud Run?

Tags: file-upload, graphql, nestjs, apollo-client, google-cloud-run

When run an application(Nest.js) on Google Cloud Run with GraphQL file upload(Apollo Server), got this error:

```
BadRequestError: Request disconnected during file upload stream parsing. at IncomingMessage.abort (/app/node_modules/graphql-upload/public/processRequest.js:127:9)
```

The source on 127 line of processRequest is `createError`:

```js
    /**
     * Handles when the request is closed before it properly ended.
     * @kind function
     * @name processRequest~abort
     * @ignore
     */
    const abort = () => {
      exit(
        createError(
          499,
          'Request disconnected during file upload stream parsing.'
        )
      );
    };
```

From this issue it seems it's necessary to use `await Promise` for `createReadStream` method:

https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/issues/149

But the file operate method already did it:

```js
    private async parseFile(...
    ...
        const parsed: ImportPoint[] = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const results = [];
          file.createReadStream().pipe(
            parse({ headers: (headers) => renameHeaders(headers, colorTypeMap) })
              .validate((data: ImportPoint, cb) =>
                validatePointRow(
                  data,
                  pointTypeColors.map((color) => color.id),
                  cb,
                ),
              )
              .on('error', (error) => reject(error))
              .on('data-invalid', (_row, rowNumber, reason) => {
                reason === INVALID_HEADER_MESSAGE && reject(new UserInputError('Bad header'));
                invalidRows.push({ row: rowNumber, columns: reason });
              })
              .on('data', (row: ImportPoint) => results.push(row))
              .on('end', () => resolve(results)),
          );
        });
```

What may be the problem?

Comment: Whenever one deals with file uploads, one might run into file size limits. It seems Nest.js is built on top of Express. One of my Cloud Run services started crashing because it came up against a size limit for uploaded files in Express. The fix was to tell Express to allow larger files than its default.

Comment: @MartinOmander But after tried a very small file still got the same issue.